# Digest Authentication support for WS client based on Java's JAX-WS implementation

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, digest-authentication

I have some web services (WCF based) exposed and have added support for both basic and digest authentication.

I have created client side stub code using jaxws-maven-plugin.

I am able to achieve basic authentication using `requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userName);
 requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);`

But as I try to invoke the web service on a server which supports just Digest authentication, it fails with 401 Authorization Error and getting WWW-Authenticate header in the SOAP response.

How can I add digest authentication support for my JAX-WS client?